# HTML Agility Pack get only InnerText for own element

Tags: html, dom, html-agility-pack

Als the title already says: I want only the "value" of current XmlNode. Not all InnerText of all sub elements as well.

```
<Bla>
asdf
    <blub>
    123
    </blub>
</Bla>
```

In the above sample "InnerText" of Element "Bla" will also return "123" even if it is nested in "blub" element.

I already found some posts where "//text()" is used but for me this returns also all "Text" elements of sub items...

It also does not help to use the first Item of the list returned when serarching by "text()" since my desired text is not always at first location since there may also be some "\r\n" elements. Yes, I know, this would be easy to remove but maybe someone can point me to a more straight forward solution?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a hack but one possibility would be to get the InnerText of the "Bla" element and then get the InnerText of the "blub" element and then just remove "blub" from "Bla" with the...  InnerTextOfblub.tostring.TrimEnd(InnerTextOfBla) ...or something like that.

I also assume you can not change the original tags? ...so that the "asdf" would be in a tag like...

```
<bla>
    <newTag>asdf</newTag>
    <blub>123</blub>
</Bla>
```

Comment: That's a nice idea! Thanks! But isn't there any "direct" way? For me this would be the "normal" behavior but I also understand why it is implemented that way.

Comment: I guess, I don't get another answer and you realy helped me... So I accept it! Thanks!